# Azure Stream Analytics Output to Data Lake Storage Gen2 with System-Assigned Managed Identity

Tags: azure-storage, azure-stream-analytics, azure-managed-identity, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a Stream Analytics Job with `Use System-assigned Managed Identity` enabled and which I would like to output its results to a Data Lake Storage Gen2.

As far as I understand I should only need to go into the Storage Account's IAM settings and add the Stream Analytics Identity as a `Stroage Blob Data Owner`. However, I don't see the Category of Stream Ananlytics Jobs in the dropdown and I can't seem to find the service principal in any of the other ones.

[image]

Am I missing something here or is this scenario just not supported yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just choose the options like below, in the `Select` option, search for the name of your `Stream Analytics Job`, then you can find it and add it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I actually tried that, but it didn't work right away. Guess I just needed to wait for some permission propagation to happen. Thanks!